# Why this python code is giving two different outputs for the same code or both are different codes?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, generator, yield

> This is Python code to print Fibonacci series using generator function.
> Code 1:

```
def test_fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(n):
        yield a
        a = b
        b = a+b
     #end of function
        
for t in test_fib(10):
    print(t)
```

> Output of code1:- 0
> 1
> 2
> 4
> 8
> 16
> 32
> 64
> 128
> 256
> Code 2:-

```
def test_fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a+b
    #end of function
        
for i in test_fib(10):
    print(i)
```

> Output of code2:- 0
> 1
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 8
> 13
> 21
> 34

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what's less clear is how it ought to be indented. Don't make us guess; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Answer (score 2):

the first code just doubles the b since we set a to b first.
the second code uses tuple unpacking so the assignment is done using previous values so it actually gives us the Fibonacci series.

Answer (score 0):

I actually enjoyed this question. Essentially what is happening when you run the Tuple unpacking in exapmle 2 is that Python doesn't "re check" the variables a and b before performing the addition.

Meaning  that when `a+b` occurs, `a!=b` yet.

Here's a minimal example of this effect.

```
a=1
a,b = a+1, a+1
print(a, b) # >>> 2 2
```

or in plain math here's whats happening

```
a,b = 1+1, 1+1
```

With your first example you are adding 1 to `a` and then adding the sum of that to `b`, with the second function the two assignments happens *at the same time* persay.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others on the idea of Tuple unpacking, but also, for the second one, you used (for 'i') twice.

Possibly could be some problem with the i-value as you never reset that variable.

Comment: `i` is in two different scopes, it wouldn't cause any issues, albeit the indenting in the question is messed up.